# How to prepend in a php loop

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<?php
$i=1;
while (i<=10)
{ ?>
    <div id="pre">
        <?php echo $i;?>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("x").prepend(document.getElementById("pre"));
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
<x></x>
```

I'm expecting the output here to be : `..4321`

instead I'm getting an output like : `21345..`

Why is only the very first output getting preprended? What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID (`pre`).

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code and this while will never exit the loop.

Comment: My god, what is the sense of that piece of code?

Comment: Sorry i just wanted to know the logic. i just roughly typed a concept and forgot to a i++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below logic where you can directly prepend values to `x` and no need to put values in div with same id

```
<?php
$i=1;
while (i<=10)
{ ?>
<script>
   $("x").prepend(<?php echo $i;?>);
</script>
<?php
   i++;
 }
?>
<x></x>
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this out.